# Access the parent Panel from a context menu?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, panel

I have a created a context menu. I'd like to only show this menu when it's called within a specific Panel. How many I get the Panel in which the context menu is being drawn? I have tried `[r.type for r in context.area.regions]`, but I'm getting `WINDOW` instead of `bpy.types.Panel`.

Thank you!

```py
class INFO_MT_props(Menu):
    bl_label = "Properties"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        #Can I access the Panel from here?
        print([r.type for r in context.area.regions]) #['HEADER', 'NAVIGATION_BAR', 'WINDOW']
        return context.space_data.type == "PROPERTIES"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
```

Comment: Your panel must be registered, you can access it from the gobal vars

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz Thank you for the message. The panel is one of Blender's native panels `DATA_PT_modifiers`. How may I access this from the global vars?

Comment: regions are always windows. I don't quite understand why you want to draw your panel only when modifiers are shown? If the panel is a 'child' of modifiers, it should be hidden automatically

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz I have operators that are specific to modifiers that would not make sense in another Properties panel. I think you meant if the `menu` is a child of the modifiers Panel? I created a menu for the Properties panel context menu in my Blender build and I'd like to change its contents based on the different types of Properties panels (e.g. 'modifiers', 'constraints'). The individual data property panels don't have their own Context Menus. They use one for all Properties (`BUTTONS_OT_context_menu`) which isn't accessible through the Python API.

Comment: can you check if space_data has a property called context?

Comment: Yes it does: `MODIFIER`!!!! @FrederikSteinmetz, you are a genius. Thank you!